# What is the difference between Val(input.Text) and input.Text in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I have this following Visual Basic code:

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()
    Dim Name1, Name2 As String
    Dim Control As String

    Name1 = txtName1.Text
    Name2 = txtName2.Text

    If Name1 = "Zoe" And Name2 = "Zoe" Then
        txtControl.Text = "the names are the same"
    Else
        txtControl.Text = "the names are different"
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that when U write `Name1 = Val(txtName1.Text)` the program doesn't work and I get "the names are different" even when they are equals, Why? What I did wrong? What is the difference between `Name1 = Val(txtName1.Text)` and `Name1 = txtName1.Text`?

Thank you!

Comment: Put `Option Strict On` at the top of the file to let the compiler tell you about mistakes like this.

Comment: In addition to everything else, `Val` is not the same as in VB6 and now fails on things it did not used to (e.g. `Val("$1.23")`).  Save yourself future headaches and switch to `Convert.ToInt32`, `Integer.Parse` and `Integer.TryParse` (each numeric type has those methods).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Val ([Here the MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) is an function still present in VB.NET to maintain some kind of compatibility with VB6.

It was used to obtain the numeric value of a string containing numbers characters.
There is no sense in applying the `Val` function to a TextBox containing a name.

However, the Val function, if cannot convert the passed string to a number, returns zero, and thus you get the error message saying the two values are different.

And, if you don't get an error message when trying to compare the result of Val (a double) with a string, then you have your [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) set to Off. A configuration that you should try to avoid at all costs (in new applications at least)

```
if Val(Name1) = "Zoe" Then

' it is equal to '
if 0# = "Zoe" Then
```

and this should be a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

`val` converts a string to a number. That’s why it can’t work.